# I keep getting this error when I try to drive my contract with the scripts

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to use the scripts from the 'Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as' to drive my own contract but I keep getting this bash error:

Which account did you authorize for use with NEAR CLI?
Enter it here (if not redirected automatically):
Logged in as [ melchizedek.testnet ] with public key [ ed25519:BmiLAN... ] successfully

gitpod /workspace/MyAssemblyContract (main) $ ./scripts/1.dev-deploy.sh
bash: ./scripts/1.dev-deploy.sh: Permission denied
gitpod /workspace/MyAssemblyContract (main) $

Everything else was working fine up to this point.

Comment: this could be happening bc gitpod doesn't give you access to the home directory but I'm not quite aure

Comment: I used Gitpod to run the Learn-Near examples and it worked fine without asking for permission. But let me check the permissions from the gitpod side.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue: I didn't have execution privileges to that file.
Funny because I had execution privileges to all the other files except this one.

Fixed it using

```
chmod u+x 1.dev-deploy.sh
```